# How can I get the music from my iPhone 3G to my hard drive using Banshee?

Tags: 11.04, banshee, iphone

I plugged in my iPhone, and it correctly detected all of my media! :)

I can play songs and browse my files, it Just Works™. Now I'd like to make a copy of all the music on my phone to my hard drive.

How can I do this? I see a `Sergio's Phone -> Music (1043)` item, and when I click my phone, I see the options to sync.

But wouldn't this delete the information on my phone? How can I just 'fetch' the data to my computer?

What do you suggest? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a bit of a hard time with this at first.

First try just right clicking on your iPhone in Banshee and selecting "Import to Library" that should theoretically import everything.

If not, install GTK-Pod from the Ubuntu Software Center, it works great for pulling music off of iPods / iPhones and organizes them with proper file titles.

Once you've loaded the iPhone and selected all the music that you want copied to your hard drive, direct it to the location of your Banshee music library. This will put all of your music where you want it and make sure that future sync's don't remove your currently loaded music.